# converting a xml into a custom widget in android

Tags: android, xml

here is my xml which i want to convert into a widget. Basically what i am doing is that inflating a layout multiple times based on user inside a loop its working bt the problem is its taking too long to inflate and application crashes if a user enters a double digit no. as input .Thats y i want to convert that layout into a widget so that i can inflate it once outside loop and then add continously inside loop. right nw i m inflating evry time inside loop before adding it.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Main_linearLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Number_relativeLayout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:background="@drawable/left">
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/num_Lyout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/measureno">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/num_txt"
                    android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Right_Main_Content">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/Upper_Right_Main_Content"
                android:background="@drawable/big">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/Left_Upper_Right_Content">
                    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:padding="10dp">
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="match_parent">
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="A(ft.)"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#076663"
                                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
                            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="0dp" android:background="@drawable/textareabg">
                                <requestFocus></requestFocus>
                            </EditText>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/Right_Upper_Right_Content">
                    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:padding="10dp">
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01">
                            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:text="A(in.)"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#076663"
                                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
                            <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/textareabg"></EditText>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/wrapper_bottom"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/bottomthis"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#076663"
                            android:id="@+id/textView5" android:text="Obstruction"></TextView>
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:button="@drawable/redio_on"
                            android:checked="true" android:id="@+id/radio_Obstruction_a"></RadioButton>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#076663"
                            android:id="@+id/textView6" android:text="Raisedwall"></TextView>
                        <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:button="@drawable/rediooff"
                            android:id="@+id/radio_Raisedwall_a"></RadioButton>
                    </RadioGroup>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: here is my java code.....  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
      
 View v= View.Inflate(this,R.layout.a,null); wrapper.addView(v);}

Comment: You have over 20 `Views` in that layout file(not to mention the nested `weights`) and if you inflate that layout `a` in that `for` loop you'll quickly have some memory and performance issues. Making a custom component(if this is what you're trying to do) will not help, either instantiating a custom view containing that layout file or inflating that layout is the same thing.

Comment: thanxxx ...then how to approach this problem...sry bt m new to android ...plss help if u can

Comment: You have to improve that layout file. No one can't help you without an image of how you want the layout to look.